# Calendar, execute code every 24 hours

Tags: android, calendar, scheduler

I would like to execute a piece of code every 24 Hours however I'm not sure how to do this.
I have some code that sets the time that I would like the cycle to start but not sure how to execute the end time

```
    int startDay = 00; // 12am
    int end = 24; // 12 pm
    int hours = (end - startDay) % 24; //difference will be 24 hours

    Calendar calInstanceOne = Calendar.getInstance();

    // set calendar to 12 am
    calInstanceOne.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startDay);
    calInstanceOne.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calInstanceOne.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calInstanceOne.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Do I create another Calendar instance, set to 12pm? and compare the two? Would really appreciate any insight into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to execute a piece of code every 24 Hours

[Use `AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), in conjunction with [either `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Ideally, [use `setInexactRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) on `AlarmManager` for `INTERVAL_DAY`, to allow Android to slide the actual time around to best save battery for the user.

Answer (score 4):

You can use AlarmManager to make actions periodically:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyStartServiceReceiver.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, <24h in msecs>, pendingIntent);
```

Then you should register your `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest and call the method you want to execute from this receiver.

Comment: Thank you, this is also an answer that helped me. Appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

> First store your current time then whenever app will be open compare current time with previous store time if its greater or equal 24 hour 
>   execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may have several choices, let me outline the easiest one. The strategy is to simply use the system time to execute twenty four hours later:

```
package com.test;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ExecuteCheck {
//Class fields
/* Number of milliseconds in a day
 * 
 */
private static final long C_DAY=24*60*60*1000;
//Object fields
/* Time last executed (or beginning of cycle), in milliseconds;
 * 
 */
private long lastExecuted = System.currentTimeMillis();

public ExecuteCheck() {
}

/** Set the current execution cycle time to now
 * 
 */
public void setExecutionTimeToNow() {
    lastExecuted = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
/** Set the execution cycle time to be the value in the calendar argument.
 * @param cal
 */
public void setExecutionTime(Calendar cal) {
    lastExecuted = cal.getTimeInMillis();   
}

/** Is it more than twenty-four hours since the last execution time?
 * @return
 */
public boolean isTimeToExecute() {
    return (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastExecuted) > C_DAY;
}
```

}